# stackoverflowのアプリって存在しますか？

Tags: サポート

stackoverflowのアプリって存在しますか？
教えて下さい

Answer (score 5):

昔は存在していましたが、2020 年前後にストアからインストールできなくなり、2022 年末に完全に使えなくなりました。詳細はこちら: [Updated: Mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/341401)

なおモバイル端末ではウェブブラウザからスタック・オーバーフローを利用できます。

Comment: そうなんですね！ありがとうございました！